# Fire and forget angular 4 http post request

Tags: angular, http-post

I am trying to make a fire and forget request but none of the options I tried are working.

The scenario is after completing one subscribable request I will be doing a redirection to some other page but before doing redirection I'm supposed to fire one more request and I do not need to wait for its response. Below is the sample what I am having now.

**FormData.ts**

```
sendData(){
   const ci = this;
   this.apiService.sendData(url, body, headers).subscribe(res => {
      ci.sendFireAndForget();
      window.location.href= this.tyredirect+".html";
   });    
}

sendFireAndForget(){
  //construct the body
  this.apiService.sendFireAndForget(url2, body);
}
```

**APIService.ts**

```
sendData(url, body, headers){
    return this._http.post(url, JSON.stringify(body), headers).map((res: Response) => res.json());
}

sendFireAndForget(emailUrl, body){
    let requestOptions = createHeader();
    this._http.post(emailUrl, body, requestOptions);
}
```

So I did not want to know what the response is and hence I did not `subscribe` or `toPromise()` to the second request. But if I do not do so, the request will not be fired.

But if I do `subscribe()` or `toPromise()` I will get **CORS did not succeed** error because of redirection.

Now, if I remove the redirection, then everything works as expected.
How can I write fire and forget method in this case?

**PS** - The Urls for both the request is to an external server.

**Edit 1**

Is there any problem with `window.location.href` for getting a CORS in this scenario?

Comment: you can subscribe to `sendFireAndForget` with a takeWhile operation, so when you are redirect, it will desotry your subscription.

Answer (score 2):

An http API in Angular returns an observable and since  observable are lazy in nature, it won't do anything until you subscribe to them.

You can simply do this:

```
 ci.sendFireAndForget().subscribe(() =>  window.location.href= this.tyredirect+".html");
```

If you don't want to subscribe, I would suggest you to use a plain XMLHttpRequest for this purpose: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/send

Comment: I do not want the user to be blocked for the second request. I just want to fire it and redirect user. If what you said was my requirement I would have done this.. :)

Comment: In that case I would suggest you to fire a simple AJAX request without using the http API. You can simply use XMLHttpRequest for this.

Comment: did we get any answer